# A PHP Loop question

Tags: php, string, loops

I'm creating a script which creates a random security number for a user, and I'm looking at ways I can complete this.

I need a security number with 7 digits but doesn't contain a 0. but when using `rand(1111111,9999999)` there is still a possibility of a `0` being inside of that number, I was wondering which loop would be best to check this and what function would I use to check for the existence of a 0 in the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couldn't you concat a random number between 1 and 9 7 times?

```
rand(1,9)
```

Answer (score 5):

This code should do what you need:

```
$num = '';
for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++)
    $num .= rand(1, 9);
$num = (int) $num;
```

It randomly generates the digits one by one and builds a string with them. Then, it changes the string to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Using while to check will not help as there will be total 9^7 cases. You don't know which case you will get next time. 
So better to use rand 7 times.

```
<?php 
function myRand($length){
$ans=0;
for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
$ans=$ans*10+rand(1,9);
}
return $ans;
}

echo myrand(7);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on base 9.

```
$p = array();
$p[0] = 1;
for ($i=1; $i<=6; $i++):
    $p[$i] = $p[$i-1] * 9;
endfor;

$max = $p[6] * 9 - 1;
$rand = rand(0,$max);

$ret = array();
for ($i=6; $i>=0; $i--):
    $tmp = $rand / $p[$i];
    $tmp = floor($tmp);
    $rand = $rand - $p[$i] * $tmp;
    $ret[] = (string)($tmp + 1);
var_dump($tmp);
endfor;

$ret = implode($ret);
var_dump($ret);
```